# Mutable versus immutable lifetime

Tags: rust

I have a program that I'm not sure how to reason about. I have a concrete lifetime defined on a trait `A`, and `A` is parameterized by a type `T : A`. One of the trait functions `refine` of `A` takes a `&'a mut self` parameter and returns a `Vec<T>`.

Suppose I have two structs `U` and `V`, such that `V` has a field with type `&'a U`, and `U` has a `refine` defined as:

```
fn refine(&'a mut self) -> Vec<V<'a>>
```

If I construct a `V` directly in the body of `U`'s implementation of `refine`, the compiler tells me that `self` doesn't live long enough. However, if I construct a `V` within an implementation function of `U`, let's call it `make_v`, whose signature is:

```
fn make_v<'a>(&'a self) -> V<'a>
```

It seems to work OK. I'm confused about how the lifetime requirements of the two are different. I have a [rust playground](http://is.gd/nbAmHU) working example, and here it is again for posterity:

```
trait A<'a, T : A<'a> = Self> {
    fn refine(&'a mut self) -> Vec<T>;
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct V<'a> {
    u: &'a U,
    id: usize
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct U {
    id: u64
}

impl U {
    fn make_v<'a>(&'a self, i: usize) -> V<'a> {
        V { u: &self, id: i }
    }
}

impl<'a> A<'a> for V<'a> {
    fn refine(&'a mut self) -> Vec<V<'a>> {
        vec![self.clone(), self.clone(), self.clone()]
    }
}

impl<'a> A<'a, V<'a>> for U {
    fn refine(&'a mut self) -> Vec<V<'a>> {
        let mut v = Vec::new();
        for i in 0..3 {
            // This doesn't compile
            // v.push(V { u: &self, id: i });

            // This does compile...?
            v.push(self.make_v(i));
        }

        v
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut u = U { id: 0 };
    println!("{:?}", u.refine());
}
```

Comment: FWIW, *lifetimes* are neither mutable nor immutable. *References* are mutable or immutable; lifetimes just represent how long the referred-to value lives.

Comment: The first version of your code works if you use `self` (or `&*self`) and not `&self` when constructing the `V` value, but I cannot figure out why this leads to a lifetime error and not a type error. In your first version, the value of `u` is a `& &mut U` when the type of `u` is `&U`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
v.push(V { u: &self, id: i });
```

is invoking *auto-deref*, so ends up as

```
v.push(V { u: *&self, id: i });
```

`&self` is a `&'k &'a mut T` where `'k` is the scope **of the `&mut` pointer** (not the pointed-to object). This means that borrows into this are at times restricted.

The `self.make_ref` version does this differently; as a reborrow. This looks like `&*self`. In this case the outer reference is into an object with lifetime `'a`, so can be of lifetime `'a`.

Just writing `self` in this case will have this handled automatically.

Credit goes to to @fjh for his comment, which clarified things nicely.